# Reference a specific commit of a remote repo

Tags: git

I would like to know if it is possible to make a reference to a specific commit and store this information in commit snapshot.

I think that an example should be more clear:
Suppose there is a remote repo "Remote1" containing some commits, e.g. A->B->C. Each commit contains a filesystem having the folder RemFold1 as first level.

Working on repo Local1 with the following filesystem:

```
LocFold1
|_ LocFold2
|_ SynchWithRemFold1
```

I would like to know if there is a way to synchronize SynchWithRemFold1 with a specific commit in Remote1, let's say A, and store this piece of information in the next commit I will perform in Local1 (in this way is directly GIT which is tracking which version of RemFold1 shall be pulled).

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear to me.  You can certainly checkout individual files at different commits, and then commit those other versions.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: Suppose I don't understand your question, what then? How can a commit contain a filesystem? If you simply want to record which commit in a different repository you're "talking about" you can simply add a text file with the name of the repository and the hash of the commit, is that what you want?

Comment: It's not entirely clear but I think you are exactly describing [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: Yes, I think submodules are the answer

Comment: The point is that I would like to have separtated hystories for each SW componets (ADC management, CPU configuration, and so on). It would be cost effective (in terms of time) to integrate by cherry picking desired version (i.e. a specific commit) of each SW component and writing some tailored code to glue them together. Git submodule are effective.